# How to handle shared object in asynchronous ajax calls

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

There are 5 parallel ajax calls happening which are trying to set the data in resulrArray with different dataType and their count as part of a function loadData.

So when dataCollection() method is getting called everyone i am getting the different count results for different dataTypes due to these parallel calls (each function is setting the unique data type value only)

How can i handle the object population properly when making parallel calls 
OR 
parallel ajax calls should not be happen for the shared object.

Adding some code for explanation

```
   app.factory("appfactory",['$q',function($q) {
  return {

    loadData:function(){
        return $q.all([this.f1(),this.f2(),this.f3(),this.f4(),this.f5()]).
        then(function(response){
            return response;
        });
    },
}]);    

app.controller('appcontroller',['$scope','appfactory',function($scope,appfactory){
    appfactory.dataCollection()
        .then(function(response){
            for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
                var dataType=response.type;
                var dataCount=response.count;
                resulrArray.push({ "dataType":dataType
                                    ,"dataCount":dataCount });
            }
        }); 

}]);
```

Comment: I personally can't understand the question. Could you provide some code?

Comment: i have modified the question and added the code also.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, a "parallel" ajax request is also known as asynchronous request. What's happening is that the second request is firing before the first request gets a chance to return a response and update the shared object. One way is to declare a synchrounous request like so...

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', '/bar/foo.txt', false);  // `false` makes the request synchronous
```

This will make the requests fire in sequence, but it's considered deprecated because it would lock the UI (to avoid extra HTTP requests) until the response arrives.

**Resource: Async and Sync**
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests

I would use a Promise. JS Frameworks, like AngularJS, handle this very neatly. But in essence you would wait until the response of the first request and then execute the second Ajax request within the "*.then*" property of the Promise. Using the response you can update your object and then feed it as a parameter to the second Ajax request. This approach won't lock your UI allowing other, non-related events to fire but would still force the second request to wait until the first one is finished, and the response returned, before executing.

**Resource: Promise**
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Figueroa, thanks for the suggestion, i have modified the question and added the piece of code which i am using .